# How to get a content from table rows as key/value pairs in regex only

Tags: php, regex, html-table

I have this table:

```
<?php 
$a ="<table class='table table-condensed'>
<tr>
<td>Monthely rent</td>
<td><strong>Fr. 1'950. </strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Rooms(s)</td>
<td><strong>3</strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Surface</td>
<td><strong>93m2</strong></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>Date of Contract</td>
<td><strong>01.04.17</strong></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

What I need is to get the value of each `<td>` inside `<tr>` as key value pairs as in:

```
monthly rent => Fr. 1'950. 
Rooms(s) => 3
Surface => 93m2
Date of Contract => 01.04.17;
```

So, far only this code returns some result close to what I need but not like the format I was expecting

```
preg_match_all("/<td>.*/", $a, $matches);
```

I am trying to find any improvements on this.

Comment: @PaulCrovella The previous question involves DOM, and is mainly a dom question, whereas this one is a regex-only question (see title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following *regex* to get the contents from table rows as *key/value* pairs :

```
regex to get keys  >>  (?<=<td>)(?!<strong>).*?(?=<\/td>)
   . . .   values  >>  (?<=<strong>).*?(?=<\/strong>)
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sWAW7o/2)

**PHP**

```
<?php
$re = '/(?<=<strong>).*?(?=<\/strong>)/';
$str = '<table class=\'table table-condensed\'>
        <tr>
        <td>Monthly rent</td>
        <td><strong>Fr. 1\'950. </strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Rooms(s)</td>
        <td><strong>3</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Surface</td>
        <td><strong>93m2</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Date of Contract</td>
        <td><strong>01.04.17</strong></td>
        </tr>
        </table>';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: This is nice, but still no way to get the array/key value pair. var_dump($result) gives a text of all the array value, I tried to echo $1 which did not work either, it seems the only thing left is to again parse the output of $result via regex again

Comment: @user7342807 check updated answer. now it should work as you expected.

Comment: Thanks, though it only returns the values but the key have no name, but i'll do for now